# Weird Active Directory DNS Issue

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2016, internal-dns

I am having a DNS issue I cannot figure out. For one specific hostname, when I create an A record, the name ends up changing when it replicates to the other DNS servers in AD.

We currently have two virtual DC/DNS servers & one physical DC/DNS server and replication is working between them. But for whatever reason when I create the record on any server, once it gets to the other ones it has an accent over one letter and the server I created it on has two entries. One with the accent and one without the accent but with the same IP.

There is only one record in the reverse lookup zone the IP is in, and I cannot create an A record or a CNAME without the accent on the servers the record is replicated to, Windows sees the text as the same.

My guess is somewhere on the servers is a remnant of the mistake I made when I initially created the record (copied and pasted without thinking) and that is causing the current issue. If anyone has any suggestion on where to look in order to fix this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Could you please also tell *which* name gets changed and to *what*? It may be important.

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner, didn't get an email notification.  gestioip was changing to gestióip, I ended up having to delete it using ADSIEdit which was nerve-wracking.

Answer (score 0):

You could try diving into the zone data using ADSIEdit.msc.  I would take a look at the zones on all the DCs with ADSIEdit and see if there are any remnants in there.  You can then delete the records directly, if there are.  **Of course, this is can be a potentially dangerous tool, so be really careful before making any changes.**

You connect using `Select or type a Distinguished Name or Naming Context` and then look at these two locations:

1. DC=ForestDNSZones,DC=contoso,DC=com
2. DC=DomainDNSZones,DC=contoso,DC=com

Obviously substituting your own actual domain DNs for Contoso.  :-)